# Regular expression to match last 3 letter pattern in a string

Tags: regex

I struggling to get a regular expression to match last 3 letter pattern in a string. For ex:, in a server name, swin2874dqs, we are looking to match last 3 letters with dxx pattern. It could be dnn, dsx, etc. 
Thank you

Comment: This is not a particularly hard regex to write. If you have tried and failed to solve this problem independently, please describe your latest attempt that has failed.

Comment: Simply [A-z]{3}$

Comment: @YuriyFaktorovich won't work since the first character of the pattern must be a 'd'

Comment: What do you match in this "foobardooo123dududu"? It's not clear if the Char before `dXX` pattern is not a letter to make the pattern valid and how mutch char a valid pattern must catch to be consider a valid pattern..

Comment: @Neb then I guess `d[A-z]{2}$`, the requirements are confusing.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assuming you only want to match letters:

```
d[a-zA-Z]{2}$
```

or

```
d[a-zA-Z]{2}\b
```

Depending if you want to match strings (first example) or words (second).